# When we appending the array on DidSelect what we have to do this to remove the exact object in DidDeselect

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, didselectrowatindexpath

I have  productArrayAny = [String: Any] and productDicAny = String:Any I am appending the productarray when fetching the data from api to make sure select all and I need to append the array the array as per product.pk and remove also same as that I tried diddeselect with the firstIndex of but it's not selecting to remove the exact product.

// fetching from api

```
 for proJSON in proArray {
                                            //   let product = wishProducts.parseProduct(proJSON: proJSON)
                                            let product = WishProducts.parseProduct(proJSON: proJSON)
                                            self.wishProducts.append(product)

                                            // extracting product array to fill the select all items
                                            self.productDicAny["product"] = product.pk
                                            switch product.uom {
                                                case "kg":
                                                    self.para["quantity"] = product.dAmount
                                                default:
                                                    self.para["quantity"] = product.amount
                                            }
```

// didselect tableview

```
let product = self.wishProducts[indexPath.row]
        self.selectedProductID = product.pk
        self.selectdQty = product.amount
self.productDicAny["product"] = product.pk
                switch product.uom {
                    case "kg":
                        self.productDicAny["quantity"] = product.dAmount
                    default:
                        self.productDicAny["quantity"] = product.amount
                }
                                                
                self.productArrayAny.append(self.productDicAny)
```

How can remove the exact product.pk item when deselecting.
I tried following all of the methods but it's not removing the exact product id when deselecting

// didDeselect

```
 let deselectIndexPath = indexPath.row
           //   print("Deselected Index Path: \(deselectIndexPath)")
            //  self.para.removeObject(forKey: "product")
            //  self.para.removeObject(forKey: "quantity")
             productArrayAny.remove(at: deselectIndexPath)
              //  let index = productArrayAny.firstIndex(of: "product": "\(String(DeslectedProductID ?? 0))")
           
              //  productArray.remove(at: index ?? 0)
           //  productArray = productArray.filter { $0 != ["product": "\(String(self.DeslectedProductID ?? 0))"] }
             //   print("Product Dictionary didDeselect : \(self.productArray)  || \(self.para)")
             //   productArray.remove(at: index ?? 0)
               // self.productDicAny.removeValue(forKey: "product")
               // self.productDicAny.removeValue(forKey: "quantity")
               // self.productArrayAny.append(self.productDicAny)
```

My dictionary response at launch

```
[["product": 6209], ["product": 8672], ["product": 9101]]
```

Comment: 1) Use a struct rather than a dictionary. 2) Add an unique identifier.

Comment: @vadian any particular example codes related to this?

Comment: Using structs is very basic object oriented programming stuff. There are millions of examples everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```objectivec
productArrayAny.beginUpdates()
productArrayAny.remove(at: deselectIndexPath)       
productArrayAny.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Please never suggest `beginUpdates/endUpdates` for a single insert/delete operation. It has no effect at all.

Comment: And we can't use begin updates here - "Value of type '[[String : Any]]' has no member 'beginUpdates'"